Triangle inequality for probability
In this post, it was proven that for random variables $a$ and $b$,
$$ P(|a+b| > c) \leq P(|a| > c/2) + P(|b|> c/2) \,.$$
What about for a sum of $k$ random variables? E.g. could we prove that
$$ P\left( \left|\sum_{i=1}^k x_i\right| > c\right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^k P\left(|x_i|> \frac{c}{k}\right) \,? $$
We can't really apply induction, because for example
\begin{align} 
P(|x_1 + x_2 + x_3| > c) 
&\leq P(|x_1 + x_2|> c/2) + P(|x_3| > c/2)
\\
&= P(|x_1| > c/4) + P(|x_2| > c/4) + P(|x_3| > c/2)
\end{align}
which has different powers of $2$ on the right hand side.

First note that for any real number $x_i$, we have
$$ -|x_i| \leq x_i \leq |x_i| $$
Therefore, summing the inequality, we have
$$ -\sum_{i=1}^k |x_i| \leq \sum_{i=1}^k x_i \leq \sum_{i=1}^k |x_i| \iff  \left| \sum_{i=1}^k x_i \right| \leq \left|\sum_{i=1}^k |x_i|\right| = \sum_{i=1}^k |x_i|$$
Next, consider the contra-positive statement: if $|x_i| \leq c/k $ for $i = 1, 2, \ldots, k$, then
$$ \left| \sum_{i=1}^k x_i \right| \leq \sum_{i=1}^k |x_i| \leq \sum_{i=1}^k \frac {c} {k} = c $$
i.e.
$$ |x_i| \leq \frac {c} {k} ~\forall i \in \{1, 2, \ldots k\} \Rightarrow
  \left| \sum_{i=1}^k x_i \right| \leq c $$
So we have the original statement
$$ \left| \sum_{i=1}^k x_i \right| > c \Rightarrow 
|x_i| > \frac {c} {k} ~\exists i \in \{1, 2, \ldots k\}  $$
Since this hold for all real-valued $x_i$, now we can translate this statement in set notation with any real-valued random variables $X_i$
$$ \left\{\left| \sum_{i=1}^k X_i \right| > c \right\} \subseteq 
\bigcup_{i=1}^k \left\{|X_i| > \frac {c} {k}\right\}$$
So the following holds for any probability:
$$ \Pr\left\{\left| \sum_{i=1}^k X_i \right| > c \right\} \leq 
\Pr \bigcup_{i=1}^k \left\{|X_i| > \frac {c} {k}\right\}
\leq \sum_{i=1}^k \Pr\left\{|X_i| > \frac {c} {k}\right\}$$
where the last inequality is the Boole's inequality.

Thank you so much for the detailed and clear explanation!

For my own reference: the reason the deterministic case implies the first statement of the random case is that the deterministic case shows that $\left| \sum_i x_i \right| > c$ implies that there must be some $i$ s.t. $|x_i| > c/k$. And that set of ${x_i}$ such that some $|x_i| > c/k$ is represented by that union.
